Latin translation of "unity in divison"
How would one translate the phrase "unity in division" into Latin?
The intended meaning is to highlight the decentralized nature of cryptocurrency.
This phrase was proposed as a Bitcoin motto in April 2011 by the user "deadlizard" on Bitcoin Talk. Here’s a link to the original discussion: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=6455.msg94663#msg94663
